# to be verb in passive voice

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

Could you tell me should I use singular or plural form of the verb to be here to make the present simple passive voice sentence

"Strawberries and cream are a very British tradition in Wimbledon.Every year,around 27,000 kilos of strawberries(1.eat) , and 7,000 litres of cream (2.use), too."

I think it's- are eaten/used  in both parts because "litres" is plural. But it gets confusing when I remember some can be exceptions even though it's plural:"a million dollars"-dollars is plural but we still use the singular article "a". as in this case, I know strawberries _is plural and cream is singar so should I say "27 000 kilos of strawberries are eaten and 7 000 litres of cream is used"?  I know cream is uncountable and with uncountable nouns if we say like litres before the word we could say plural or singular but it will depend on the context like:two litres of water is used -we mean water as a whole substance? and when we say "are used"-we mean only litres? 
Thanks everyone for explaining in advance and sorry for any mistakes :)

Comment: The countable amount makes it plural as you thought. Two litres (of cream, or water) are used. Take the amount away and it becomes "is used." Dollars, "a" is a way of saying "one." We're not saying "one of a 'million dollars'" but one million of them.

Comment: In "a million dollars", "a" belongs to "million" and not "million dollars" which is why a singular indefinite article is used.